# Installing the Joomla Framework

Tags: joomla, github, frameworks, composer-php, joomla-framework

I am trying to install the Joomla 1.0 framework onto a project I am working on.

I did a build from composer, and github both with no dice. How do I get the framework into my project?

I did all of the steps in the documentation, but it did nothing but error out.

```
Warning: require_once(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fundraising/reports/libraries/import.legacy.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fundraising/reports/reports.php on line 25

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fundraising/reports/libraries/import.legacy.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fundraising/reports/reports.php on line 25
```

Above are the 2 errors I got.

I am not finding the files I need in any of the downloads. Has anyone else been able to succesfully install and use the framework?

Thanks

Comment: You need to explain a little more of what you did.  When you say "install" do you mean you you tried to get the files from composer and the files didn't come? Did you try to get the whole thing or just some specific packages?  Can you just confirm that you did or didn't get files from composer?  Because it looks like what you you are doing is trying to run an application that is written for the specific older version of the framework that ships with the CMS and includes a lot of other things, not an application for the framework.

Comment: I did get the files from composer, from the latest pull from joomla framework. I also ran through the tutorial from joomla to get the code working, but that is where I am getting the error from.

Comment: I think you are using an application that assumes the CMS version of the framework/platform.  Hence your application is importing the legacy library from the cms, but you don't have that since you just have the framework which doesn't include any of the CMS or legacy packages.  If you are writing a new application you may not need those at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to do the "hello world" examples from http://docs.joomla.org/Framework:Creating_a_Stand-alone_Application . To solve it I copied the whole library from a Joomla instalation in the main directory and worked fine. 
But this fix is not the right solution since the aim of the framework is to be independent from the CMS library. In fact, there are some other example of Joomla framework Apps, that work without the libraries. https://github.com/mbabker/framework-app

One more thing: I had to add a line `require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/cms.php';` in oder to avoid a problem with the class JRegistry, that was doesn't exist anymore in J3.3 https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/3374 .`